tag for slang shader language
In the most recent release of the Vulkan SDK, support for a new shader language (slang) was added. I was unable to find any tag for this language and unable to create a tag "slang" as it was too similar to "s-lang". Can we get a tag to refer to this new shader language?

Be sure to read the guidance FAQ on when and how to create new tags

"Can we get a tag to refer to this new shader language?" Tags aren't created for the sake of existing; they are created as part of a question being asked. If there's no questions about slang, then there's no need to create the tag. Is ther a question you have asked, or a question you've seen, that you feel should be tagged with [[tag:slang]]? I would, however, suggest that if this topic is appropriate for [so], that [[tag:slang-lang]] would like be a better tag, so that it isn't ambiguous with the existing [[tag:s-lang]].

Alternatively, as the website for the language is Shader Slang, perhaps [[tag:shader-slang]] would be appropriate?

@ThomA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79099865/implementing-a-custom-islangfilesystem

Considering that s-lang already exists (though with 4 questions, has no wiki, and ambiguous itself as it could be about S Language or S-lang), I would suggest that having a tag named slang could easily result in ambiguity. I would therefore suggest a different name for the tag. A few suggestions are:

slang-lang - There are quite a few languages that have the -lang suffix on their tag names, to avoid ambiguity.
shader-slang - This copies the name of the website for the language, as well as the GitHub account for the language. Probably not my personal choice, but an option.
slang-shading-lang\slang-shading-language - "Slang Shading Language" is the name the official VS Code Extension refers to the language as.

As someone who know's nothing about the language, I feel like the last might be the most unambiguous and "best™" candidate for the tag's name (if only because "Slang lang" feels a bit like saying "ATM Machine").

I vote for [shader-slang] like the website. Slang-lang sound like a joke-oke.

Yeah, it kind of "bugs" me about [[tag:slang-lang]], @VLAZ, as it most closely follows the precedence set but other tags, but it's yuck to read.

I think just slang makes the most sense, as it lines up best with similar tags (glsl, hlsl, c++) and it seems silly to me to worry about ambiguity with a tag that only has 4 questions. Maybe someone can create this and edit the descriptions for clarity. If not, then I'll just have to see what alternatives are available next time I ask a question about it.

@DavidCarpenter ambiguity should not be reasoned only from the status quo but from the future as well. We now have a long history of tag rename / burnination meta posts because no care was taken to make tag names stand the test of time when it was still only a small fix. At some point it is time to make better choices rather than making it a problem for future meta dwellers to get an eye sore over.
